# Bootstrap navbar center with two lists

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

How do you get a bootstrap navbar ul to be centered, but ignore the space occupied by another ul, so that the center is truly centered, and not shifted?

I have two unordered lists in my bootstrap navbar. I want one of them (#clause) to be centered, and the other (#social-icons) to be on the right.

But what happens is the centered one is slightly to the left of absolute center because the one on the right takes up some of the space.

Thus the centering is calculated based on the remaining space, rather than the entire width

Here is my code so far:
Currently, I have the right-aligned list within the other list. They should be two separate lists. But when I separate them, I run into the problem of each of them wanting their own rows.

I am using bootstrap 3

**css**

```
#navbar {
  #clause {
    text-align: center;

    li {
      font-size: 1.6em;
      float: none;
      display: inline-block;
      *display: inline;
      *zoom:1;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
  }

  #social-icons {

  }

}
```

**navbar HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="clause">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <ul class="nav navbar-right" id="social-icons">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: this is not code by any means, unless the definition of code has changed. Please include proper code so we can test, help us help you

Comment: @Fabio Its Jade (for HTML) and SASS or LESS (For CSS), works just fine on CodePen.

Comment: then you should add your CodePen , because it doesn't work for me. Anyways, just trying to help you, but you do whatever you want

Comment: @Fabio its not my question... simply pointing out that it is valid code. Though it would have been helpful for the person asking the question to specify the languages and frameworks being used...

Comment: @Fabio converted to html. I was thinking the general idea of the layout would have been sufficient, which was more cleanly represented in the preprocessor DSL of slim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore the space occupied by the list #social-icons make its position absolute.
Doing so will give the whole width to #clause

CSS

```
  #social-icons {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
  }
```